# Private canonical constructor for record

Tags: java, scala, data-structures, record

Creating immutable data structures, I really like the concept of Scala, where you can enforce object instantiation *only* via factory method in this way using case class (having a private canonical constructor) and companion object.

```scala
final case class Foo private(a: Int)

object Foo {
  def apply(left: Int, right: Int) = Foo(left + right)
}
```

With Java 14, the concept of [records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/records.html) have been introduced, providing most of Scala's case class features.
However, making the canonical constructor of records `private` seems to be a bit cumbersome... Is there any way to achieve the same behavior with Java's records?

Answer (score 7):

In case, you want to **make some sanity checks (or other additions) in factory method, you can use Compact constructor** of record (i.e. constructor without parameters part). For example:

```
record HelloWorld(String message) {
    public HelloWorld {
        java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(message);
    }
}
```

Through it will not hide canonical constructor, but it will "append" it with code provided (sanity checks, automatic registrations, ...)

**Record cannot hide its canonical constructor** like it is possible in case class from scala. "java" way for doing this is **using class** with private constructor:

```
public class Foo private {
    private final Integer a;
    private Foo(Integer a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public Foo of(Integer left, Integer right) {
        return new Foo(left + right);
    }
}
```

Through using opinionated lombok library, you can lower down boilerplate to scala level:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Foo private {
    private final Integer a;

    public Foo of(Integer left, Integer right) {
        return new Foo(left + right);
    }
}
```

If you are already using lombok, you can be interested in its immutable annotation called [@Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value).

Comment: lombok 1.18.22 doesn't support adding `@RequiredArgsConstructor` on anything other than class or enum.

Comment: What's this word "private" between class name and "{"?

Comment: you can't put private after the class name in java, and a private class wouldn't do what someone wants.

Comment: I thought maybe your syntax is some preview feature, but now I've even tried with the latest Java 22 with `--enable-preview` and it still doesn't accept your code: `Foo.java:1: error: '{' expected`.